# DirectoryEntry ActiveDirectorySyntax.Int64 Property hint on how to format as date or number

Tags: .net, active-directory, directoryentry

I want to display all properties of an ActiveDirectory user entry like the Attribute Editor in the properties dialog shown when “View”->”Advanced Features” in “Active Directory Users and Computers” is activated.

This is a rather simple task by using `DirectorySearcher` function `FindOne` and then iterating through the `SearchResult`.

From the `ActiveDirectorySchemaProperty` I get the syntax like `ActiveDirectorySyntax.Int64`. But now I wonder if there is a hint on how to format this “Large Integer” values. Some of them obviously should be shown as dates like `lastLogon`, others just as the numeric value like `maxStorage`.

Does anybody have an idea on how to get that information programmatically out of the AD somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

use .ToFileTime

for example:

```
DateTime date = Datetime.Now;
long int64Date = date.ToFileTime();
```

and, use .FromFileTime to convert the long value to Datetime